# Delete records from last 10 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns `id(NUMBER), log_dt(TIMESTAMP)`.

I need to delete the data of last 10 days based on the `log_dt` column.

I tried the below query but it didn't work, since it is not considering the year:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Test
WHERE log_dt >= SYSDATE-10;
```

Please help.

Comment: Your query (not delete) is comparing a timestamp with a date, so it will consider the year. Pleaseedit you question to explain why you think it is, and include same data, current end expected results.

Comment: Do you need this `DELETE Test WHERE log_dt >=TRUNC(sysdate)-10` ?

Comment: when you do a count(*) TRUNC(log_dt ) >= trunc(sysdate) - 10 , do you see the count reflecting the rows from the previous years?

Comment: @AlexPoole: `SYSDATE` includes a time part in Oracle so it's comparing two "timestamp" values with a different precision (microseconds vs. seconds) It's definitely not "considering the year"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it's "considering the year" as much as all the other components; it isn't including data from previous years (obviously). It isn't *only* considering the year but that isn't what the OP was asking for. Anyway, unless the OP provides clarification of why what they've tried isn't giving the result they said they want, not much we can do except guess and misinterpret things.